# Finding the most compact representation of a vector in an "overdetermined base"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to find the most compact representation of a vector as a linear combination of a set of vectors B. B has more elements (on purpose) that is needs to have to describe the subspace.

For example

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0
```

Given

```
0 2 2 1
```

I want to obtain:

```
0 0 0 1 2
```

and not

```
0 2 2 1 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `0 0 0 1 2`? How do you define "the most compact"? Only in terms of the number of (non)zero elements, or is there something else as well?

Comment: @VedranŠego: You are right. I miss typed. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem and various related problems are known to be NP-hard to solve exactly, but there has been a lot of work on efficient approximations.  See [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_approximation) or try googling things like "sparsest vector", "LASSO", "Orthogonal Matching Pursuit".

None of these methods will guarantee the sparsest solution with a particular fixed choice of vectors $B$.  But if the set $B$ is large then maybe you don't care about having the exact smallest representation as long as you get a decent one.  If the set $B$ is small (as in the example you gave), of course you can enumerate all the subsets and try them one by one.

Comment: Thanks. It works quite nice most of the times. Look at my edit.

Comment: @Hernan: You're welcome.  Unfortunately I don't know much about the details of this algorithm.  The recommended procedure on MO for asking follow-up questions is to post a new question which links to the old one; you would probably get more answers this way since some people are more likely to look at questions which do not yet have an accepted answer.